# Clean workspace, plot pane, and console on rerun in Julia

Tags: julia, juno-ide

I am used to starting all my Matlab scripts with `clear all; close all; clc` to ensure I am not looking at any old data or plots. I found Julia's `clearconsole()` to be equivalent to Matlab's `clc`, but don't have working solutions for the other two Matlab commands yet. I mostly work in the Juno IDE and run scripts with the Play ("Run All") button.

The Revise.jl package is supposed to clear the workspace now that `workspace()` is deprecated, but it doesn't work for this simple test case. If I define `x` once and then comment that line out, it will continue to print each time I run without error.

```
using Revise
clearconsole()
#x=1
println(x)
```

I know I can hit "Stop" then "Play" to reset the workspace. However, that still doesn't close old plots, and the [time to first plot issue](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/roadmap-for-a-faster-time-to-first-plot/22956) makes this option undesirable.

I found the "Forget All Plots" button in Juno's plot pane, but I would like to have that functionality as a line in my script instead. Currently, it takes me three clicks to run a script again after I edit it (four if I include "Stop").

1. "Forget All Plots"
2. Somewhere in the editor to put focus back on my current file.
3. "Run All"

I would ideally like to rerun in a fresh environment with one click or keystroke, but any tips on a better Juno workflow would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think Revise will clear anything. It will just update things when the underlying file changes.

Comment: @phipsgabler What do you mean by "update things"?

Comment: Mostly updating the method table according to the changes you made in the files (just like when you redefine a function in the REPL).  This does not work for types, though. Definitions that are not changed are left as they were before, not cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered on the Julia discourse website: [link](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/clean-workspace-plot-pane-and-console-on-re-run-in-julia/39475).

- `Juno.clearconsole()` may be used like Matlab's `clc`.
- Writing a script within a module will clear the variables upon each run like Matlab's `clear all`.
- A new function may be added to Juno.jl in the future which will work like Matlab's `close all`.